# JSON Array Logic Problem

Tags: java, android, json

Hy!

JSON:

```
{
   "responseData":{
      "countries":[
         {
            "name":"\u00d6sterreich",
            "id":"1",
            "channels":[
               {
                  "name":"ARD",
                  "id":"3"
               },
               {
                  "name":"ORF 1",
                  "id":"1"
               },
               {
                  "name":"ORF 2",
                  "id":"2"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "name":"Deutschland",
            "id":"2",
            "channels":[
               {
                  "name":"ARD",
                  "id":"3"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   "responseDetails":null,
   "responseStatus":200
}
```

Java Code:

```
JsonObject obj = new JSONParse(text);
JSONObject menuobj = this.getJSONObject("responseData");
```

How to access the array with the countries?

THX

Comment: When posting JSON, you may want to format it using:
http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Are you sure it is this.getJSONObject and not obj.getJSONObject in your example code?

Comment: @kayahr you are right i copied it from a derived class form JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
JSONArray countries = menuObj.getJSONArray("countries");
```